# How does libprocessgroup in Android work?

Tags: android, android-source, activity-manager

Lets say an application process is started by the zygote, with PID 1234. When the app launches, PID: 1234 forks another process, say with PID: 1300. When I exit the app, PID: 1234 is killed with a signal 9 (SIGKILL). PID: 1300 then becomes an orphaned process and is adopted by the init process (PID: 1). Soon, the libprocessgroup triggers and kills PID: 1300 also (as part of the processgroup of PID: 1234). How is this triggered? In other words, when does libprocessgroup swoop into the picture to cleanup the remaining processes?